# Looping through session variables with LINQ?

Tags: linq, session

So I'm still rather new to LINQ, so bear with me. I'm trying to check the session variables and if the variable name doesn't contain the key with the name "Selected" then set the value of it to null.

This is what I have, though I'm probably not close:

```
Session.Keys.Cast<string>().Where(k => !k.Contains("Selected")).ToList().ForEach(k => k = null);
```

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The LINQ you have is setting the key to null.  I believe this is what you need to actually set the value:

```
Session.Keys.Cast<string>()
            .Where(k => !k.Contains("Selected"))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(k => Session[k] = null);
                          ^
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the full expanded LINQ form

```
Session.Keys
  .Cast<string>()
  .Where(k => !k.Contains("Selected")
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(k => Session[k] = null);
```

For this particular case I find a mix of LINQ and `foreach` to be much more readable:

```
foreach (var key in Session.Keys.Cast<string>().Where(k => !k.Contains("Selected").ToList())) {
  Session[key] = null;
}
```

Comment: Given the lack of support for the .ForEach extension in Windows 8 metro, I'm quickly weaning myself off of it, and going back to the traditional ForEach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative, more functional solution:

```
Session = Session.ToDictionary(it => it.Key, 
              it => (it.Key as string).Contains("Selected") ? it.Value : null);
```

The trade-off is it creates a new dictionary.